# Decomposition of a compact Hausdorff $S$ space by a closed self-adjoint algebra in $C(S)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

The following question is from Chapter IX in *Linear Operaotrs* edited by **Dunford & Schwartz**, Exercise 4.1

Let $S$ be a compact Hausdorff topological space and $C(S)$ be all complex continuous functions defined on $S$. For a $f \in C(S)$, let $f^*(x) = \overline{f(x)}$ be the involution. Now assume $\mathfrak{A}$ is a closed unital self-adjoint subalgebra of $C(S)$. Then show that there exists a decomposition of $S$ into a (disjoint) union of closed sets (say $\dot\bigcup_{\lambda \in \Lambda} F_{\lambda}$) on each of which all elements of $\mathfrak{A}$ will be constant($\forall\,f \in \mathfrak{A}\,\forall\,\lambda \in \Lambda, f\vert_{F_{\lambda}}$ is constant), and such that each continuous function that is constant on each $F_{\lambda}$ belongs to $\mathfrak{A}$.

It is proved that in a compact Hausdorff space $X$, each closed ideal $\mathcal{I}$ in $C(X)$ injectively correspond to a closed set $F \subset X$ such that $\mathcal{I} = \mathcal{I}_F = \{g \in C(X)\,\vert\,g\vert_F = 0\}$. In the above question, I do not know how to use this result. Should we partition $\mathfrak{A}$ by intersection of ideals?

Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the equivalence between compact spaces and C*-algebras a la Gelfand? Then, at least if U has identity, you can look at the spectrum T of U, and the inclusion U to C(S) will correspond to a continuous map S to T, and the fibers of this map are the sets F_{\lambda} you are looking for...

Comment: The statement is false if you don't require $\mathfrak{A}$ to contain the identity.

Comment: @Sasha If I let $\overset{\wedge}{s}(f) = f(s)$, by saying the mapping of $S$ to $T$ do you mean this mapping $s \rightarrow \overset{\wedge}{s} \vert_{\mathfrak{A}}$? This mapping is not scalar-valued. Can you specify your mapping here?

Comment: @EricWofsey If it does not contain the identity, can we consider $\mathfrak{A}\,\bigoplus\,\mathbb{C} I$? I believe I can assume $\mathfrak{A}$ contains an identity but I would like know your counterexample.

Comment: Literally any $\mathfrak{A}$ which does not contain the identity is a counterexample.  For instance, $\mathfrak{A}=\{0\}$.

Comment: @EricWofsey I got it now. Let me edit the question now.

Comment: Yes, I believe that in your notation I mean this mapping. What do you mean by "scalar-valued"? it should not be scalar valued, it is a mapping from S to T. To a point s in S you associate the point in T, the spectrum of U, the value at which, for f \in C(T) \cong U \subset S is f(s) via this inclusion

Comment: More generally, you would like to know, by the general theory, that to a morphism A \to B of unital commutative C^* algebras there corresponds a continuous map Spec(B) \to Spec(A) of the corresponding compact Hausdorff spaces. We then apply this general thing to our inclusion U \to C(S).

Comment: @Sasha Thank you for your hints. I just tried your solution and noticed that because the inclusion mapping $\iota: \mathfrak{A} \rightarrow C(S)$ is injective, the induced mapping $\overset{\wedge}{\iota}: S = Spec[C(S)] \rightarrow T$ will also be injective. In this case each fibre of $\overset{\wedge}{\iota}$ will be a singleton.

Comment: @Sasha In this case the second statement: "A function that is constant in each $F_{\lambda}$ also belong to $\mathfrak{A}$" fails because all functions in $C(S)$ does so. Or there is something wrong with my understanding?

Comment: what you write is not correct; if A \to B is injective then Spec(B) \to Spec(A) tends to be surjective, not injective. Everything gets swapped...

Comment: My bad... You are absolutely right. Thank you for your second solution! I will put your replies together and then mention your name in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  Thinking in terms of decompositions into closed sets here is rather misleading.  Rather, what you want to think about is the *equivalence relation* on $S$ defined by the partition of $S$ into the $F_\lambda$.  Can you describe what that equivalence relation ought to be, in terms of $\mathfrak{A}$?  (What equivalence relation does $\mathfrak{A}$ naturally define on $S$, such that each element of $\mathfrak{A}$ is constant on the equivalence classes?)  Now use Stone-Weierstrass on the quotient of $S$ by this equivalence relation to show that it has the desired properties.

More details are hidden below.

> Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $S$ by $x\sim y$ iff $f(x)=f(y)$ for all $f\in\mathfrak{A}$.  Our partition $\{F_\lambda\}$, if it exists (and corresponds to a closed equivalence relation), must consist of the equivalence classes of this equivalence relation.  So let $T$ be the quotient space $S/{\sim}$; since $\sim$ is a closed equivalence relation, $T$ is also compact Hausdorff.  Note moreover that by the universal property of the quotient space, we can identify $C(T)$ with the subalgebra of $C(S)$ consisting of functions that are constant on each equivalence class of $\sim$.  With this identification, the definition of $\sim$ immediately implies $\mathfrak{A}\subseteq C(T)$, and we wish to prove that $\mathfrak{A}=C(T)$.
>
>  To do this, we apply Stone-Weierstrass.  Since $\mathfrak{A}$ is a closed self-adjoint unital subalgebra of $C(T)$, it suffices to show that it separates points of $T$.  In other words, if $A$ and $B$ are two distinct equivalence classes of $\sim$, we wish to find a function $f\in\mathfrak{A}$ which takes different values on $A$ and $B$.  But this is immediate from the definition of $\sim$: if no such $f$ existed, then any $a\in A$ would be equivalent to any $b\in B$, so they would not be distinct equivalence classes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! By saying "universal property of the quotient space", do you know any references where I can find countent relevant to this topic? In general, if $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $\sim$ is a closed equivalent relation, is $C(X / \sim)$ equal to the subalgebra (of $C(X)$) where each element in that subalgebra is constant in each equivalent class?

Comment: By "universal property of the quotient space" I just mean that continuous maps $T\to Y$ for any space $Y$ are in bijection with continuous maps $S\to Y$ which are constant on the equivalence classes, by composing with the quotient map $S\to T$.  You should be able to find a discussion of this in any pointset topology textbook.

Comment: Applying this with $Y=\mathbb{C}$ immediately gives an isomorphism between $C(X/{\sim})$ and the subalgebra of $C(X)$ consisting of functions that are constant on the equivalence classes.

Comment: I got it. Now this is clear. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

$\hspace{0.44cm}$**According to @Sasha's ideas**, because the inclusion mapping $\iota: \mathfrak{A} \rightarrow C(S)$ is a injective continuous mapping between $C^*$-Algebra, its induced mapping $\overset{\wedge}{\iota}$ from the spectrum of $\mathfrak{A}$, say $\mathcal{M}_{\mathfrak{A}}$, to the spectrum of $C(S)$ (which is homeomorphic to $S$) will be a surjective continuous mapping. Hence for each $\phi \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathfrak{A}}$ and each $g \in \mathfrak{A}, g \vert_{(\overset{\wedge}{\iota})^{-1}\,\{\phi\}} = \phi(g)$ and $\{(\overset{\wedge}{\iota})^{-1}\,\{\phi\}\}_{\phi \in \mathfrak{A}}$ is the desired decomposition. Call each set $S_{\phi}$

$\hspace{0.44cm}$ Given a function $h \in C(S)$ that is constant in each $S_{\phi}$, we have $\overset{\wedge}{h}(\phi) = h \vert_{S_{\phi}}$ is a well-defined element in $C[\mathcal{M}_{\mathfrak{A}}]$ and hence $h \in \mathfrak{A}$.